# How to make checkboxes grey in a cxGrid column

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-7

In cxGrid I have a column with property `Options.Editing:=False; Properties:=CheckBox`. So, user can not change state of the checkboxes. But the checkboxes still have custom color and user does't see that he can not edit them.

How do I make checkboxes grey in a cxGrid column, which one can not edit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use OnCustomDrawCell event to draw a disabled checkbox.

Check out: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q253981.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You could make an OnCustomDrawCell event on the grid view, with something like:

```
if not AViewInfo.Item.Options.Editing then
  ACanvas.Brush.Color := clGray;
```

Answer (score 1):

Columns that are not editable will not become grey. This goes for all kinds of editors, be they checkboxes, textedits or whatever. The checkbox has a property for NullStyle that can be set to nssGrayedChecked, but this will only be displayed for NULL values.

You have some other options, though. The simplest may be to set the column to not focusable, as well as not editable (Options.Focusing = false). This will perhaps make it easier for your users to understand why they can't change the value. THe second easiest option is to use a custom style that in some way indicates a disabled/noneditable column, for instance by having a grey background color.

Comment: Thank you, Svein. I thought about this approuches but they are not as good as I want. If I will not find better solution I will use custom style.

Answer (score 0):

Use cxStyleRepository

```
<TcxGridDbColumn>.styles.Content
```